# Boolean after Bevel, using difference doesn't work correct

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm using latest blender 2.82.7.
Steps:

1. Create box and bevel the edges on the top, to be like arc.
2. Shade smooth and auto smoothing.
3. I have other box and I try to boolean.

The object are like Union, instead of Difference.

During boolean:

[image: During boolean]

After apply of boolean:
[image: After boolean]

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Your smaller beveled object is not manifold. Select all vertices > Alt-M > 'By distance' to remove double vertices and zero-sized faces.

Comment: Ha, here is the funny part: I followed your steps and at the first try - it work. I didn't save and quit then open again and at the second time - did not work. Ah...

Comment: It will work.. check around the start of the bevel for double verts. Move them about a bit and right-click to drop them back where they came from.

Comment: Wow, you are right. I didn't know how to select All, ctrl+a doesn't work, but only A it seems is the key. So after select All and repeat steps - Hooray! Thank you very much for the encouragement!

Comment: A to select all, Alt-A or double-A to deselect all.